# Regarding NIGHT SHIFT Employees

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, stored-procedures

I have small issue on **night shift** of our employees. Shift timings are from 22:00 to 6:00. If the shift starts today at 11 PM it will end the next morning at 6:00 AM (7 Hours ).

Here I want to know the first Swipe in and last Swipe out. Below table structure and some sample data are provided along with the expected output.

I need a procedure with inputs like @loginname, @startdate, @Enddate

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CardData](
 [CardDataID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
 [DataMovementHistoryID] [bigint] NULL,
 [LoginName] [varchar](200) NULL,
 [ShiftID] [int] NULL,
 [CardTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 [IsInOrOut] [bit] NULL,
 [IsProcessed] [bit] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**Test case 1**

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[CardData] ([CardDataID], [DataMovementHistoryID], [LoginName], [ShiftID], [CardTime], [IsInOrOut], [IsProcessed]) VALUES (11290, 2200, 'B1000', 1, CAST(N'2019-06-01 9:24:00.000' AS DateTime), 1, 1)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[CardData] ([CardDataID], [DataMovementHistoryID], [LoginName], [ShiftID], [CardTime], [IsInOrOut], [IsProcessed]) VALUES (11291, 2200, 'B1000', 1, CAST(N'2019-06-01 12:55:00.000' AS DateTime), 0, 1)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[CardData] ([CardDataID], [DataMovementHistoryID], [LoginName], [ShiftID], [CardTime], [IsInOrOut], [IsProcessed]) VALUES (11292, 2200, 'B1000', 1, CAST(N'2019-06-01 15:24:00.000' AS DateTime), 1, 1)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[CardData] ([CardDataID], [DataMovementHistoryID], [LoginName], [ShiftID], [CardTime], [IsInOrOut], [IsProcessed]) VALUES (11293, 2200, 'B1000', 1, CAST(N'2019-06-01 17:55:00.000' AS DateTime), 0, 1)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[CardData] ([CardDataID], [DataMovementHistoryID], [LoginName], [ShiftID], [CardTime], [IsInOrOut], [IsProcessed]) VALUES (11294, 2200, 'B1000', 1, CAST(N'2019-06-02 10:24:00.000' AS DateTime), 0, 1)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[CardData] ([CardDataID], [DataMovementHistoryID], [LoginName], [ShiftID], [CardTime], [IsInOrOut], [IsProcessed]) VALUES (11295, 2200, 'B1000', 1, CAST(N'2019-06-02 13:55:00.000' AS DateTime), 1, 1)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[CardData] ([CardDataID], [DataMovementHistoryID], [LoginName], [ShiftID], [CardTime], [IsInOrOut], [IsProcessed]) VALUES (11296, 2200, 'B1000', 1, CAST(N'2019-06-02 14:24:00.000' AS DateTime), 0, 1)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[CardData] ([CardDataID], [DataMovementHistoryID], [LoginName], [ShiftID], [CardTime], [IsInOrOut], [IsProcessed]) VALUES (11297, 2200, 'B1000', 1, CAST(N'2019-06-02 16:01:00.000' AS DateTime), 0, 1)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[CardData] ([CardDataID], [DataMovementHistoryID], [LoginName], [ShiftID], [CardTime], [IsInOrOut], [IsProcessed]) VALUES (11295, 2200, 'B1000', 1, CAST(N'2019-06-03 08:24:00.000' AS DateTime), 1, 1)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[CardData] ([CardDataID], [DataMovementHistoryID], [LoginName], [ShiftID], [CardTime], [IsInOrOut], [IsProcessed]) VALUES (11296, 2200, 'B1000', 1, CAST(N'2019-06-03 13:55:00.000' AS DateTime), 0, 1)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[CardData] ([CardDataID], [DataMovementHistoryID], [LoginName], [ShiftID], [CardTime], [IsInOrOut], [IsProcessed]) VALUES (11297, 2200, 'B1000', 1, CAST(N'2019-06-03 15:24:00.000' AS DateTime), 0, 1)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[CardData] ([CardDataID], [DataMovementHistoryID], [LoginName], [ShiftID], [CardTime], [IsInOrOut], [IsProcessed]) VALUES (11298, 2200, 'B1000', 1, CAST(N'2019-06-03 17:01:00.000' AS DateTime), 1, 1)
```

**Parameters**

```
---@loginname = 'B1000' 
---@startdate = '2019-06-01'
---@Enddate = '2019-06-15'
```

**Required Output**

```
loginname   |   DT          |     FirstIn           |  InFlag   |      LastOut          | OutFlag   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
B1000       |   2019-06-02  |   2019-06-02 10:24:00 |   0       |   2019-06-02 16:01:00 |   0   
B1000       |   2019-06-03  |   2019-06-03 8:24:00  |   1       |   2019-06-03 17:01:00 |   1
```

**Test case 2**

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[CardData] ([CardDataID], [DataMovementHistoryID], [LoginName], [ShiftID], [CardTime], [IsInOrOut], [IsProcessed]) VALUES (11299, 2200, 'C2000', 8, CAST(N'2019-07-01 23:05:00.000' AS DateTime), 0, 1)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[CardData] ([CardDataID], [DataMovementHistoryID], [LoginName], [ShiftID], [CardTime], [IsInOrOut], [IsProcessed]) VALUES (11300, 2200, 'C2000', 8, CAST(N'2019-07-02 00:55:00.000' AS DateTime), 0, 1)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[CardData] ([CardDataID], [DataMovementHistoryID], [LoginName], [ShiftID], [CardTime], [IsInOrOut], [IsProcessed]) VALUES (11301, 2200, 'C2000', 8, CAST(N'2019-07-02 3:24:00.000' AS DateTime), 1, 1)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[CardData] ([CardDataID], [DataMovementHistoryID], [LoginName], [ShiftID], [CardTime], [IsInOrOut], [IsProcessed]) VALUES (11302, 2200, 'C2000', 8, CAST(N'2019-07-02 5:05:00.000' AS DateTime), 1, 1)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[CardData] ([CardDataID], [DataMovementHistoryID], [LoginName], [ShiftID], [CardTime], [IsInOrOut], [IsProcessed]) VALUES (11303, 2200, 'C2000', 8, CAST(N'2019-07-03 23:24:00.000' AS DateTime), 1, 1)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[CardData] ([CardDataID], [DataMovementHistoryID], [LoginName], [ShiftID], [CardTime], [IsInOrOut], [IsProcessed]) VALUES (11304, 2200, 'C2000', 8, CAST(N'2019-07-04 02:55:00.000' AS DateTime), 0, 1)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[CardData] ([CardDataID], [DataMovementHistoryID], [LoginName], [ShiftID], [CardTime], [IsInOrOut], [IsProcessed]) VALUES (11305, 2200, 'C2000', 8, CAST(N'2019-07-04 4:24:00.000' AS DateTime), 1, 1)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[CardData] ([CardDataID], [DataMovementHistoryID], [LoginName], [ShiftID], [CardTime], [IsInOrOut], [IsProcessed]) VALUES (11306, 2200, 'C2000', 8, CAST(N'2019-07-04 05:57:00.000' AS DateTime), 0, 1)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[CardData] ([CardDataID], [DataMovementHistoryID], [LoginName], [ShiftID], [CardTime], [IsInOrOut], [IsProcessed]) VALUES (11307, 2200, 'C2000', 8, CAST(N'2019-07-05 23:24:00.000' AS DateTime), 1, 1)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[CardData] ([CardDataID], [DataMovementHistoryID], [LoginName], [ShiftID], [CardTime], [IsInOrOut], [IsProcessed]) VALUES (11308, 2200, 'C2000', 8, CAST(N'2019-07-06 02:57:00.000' AS DateTime), 0, 1)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[CardData] ([CardDataID], [DataMovementHistoryID], [LoginName], [ShiftID], [CardTime], [IsInOrOut], [IsProcessed]) VALUES (11309, 2200, 'C2000', 8, CAST(N'2019-07-06 04:24:00.000' AS DateTime), 0, 1)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[CardData] ([CardDataID], [DataMovementHistoryID], [LoginName], [ShiftID], [CardTime], [IsInOrOut], [IsProcessed]) VALUES (11310, 2200, 'C2000', 8, CAST(N'2019-07-06 05:57:00.000' AS DateTime), 1, 1)
```

**Parameters**

```
---@loginname = 'C2000' 
---@startdate = '2019-07-01'
---@Enddate = '2019-07-15'
```

**Required output**

```
loginname   |  DT         |   FIrstIN           | InFLag |     Lastout         | Outflag  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
C2000       |  2019-07-01 | 2019-07-01 23:05:00 |    0   | 2019-07-01 5:05:00  |   1   
C2000       |  2019-07-05 | 2019-07-05 23:24:00 |    1   | 2019-07-05 05:57:00 |   1
```

Comment: I'm confused - when you say shift times run from 10PM to 6AM, what about the examples above where the shift is not in those times?

Comment: yeah, Either your `Biz Rule` is not complete yet or `Incomplete` info provided.We need to know.I tried for what u r looking for,then I realize info is not complete.You have to follow biz rules to accomplice what you are looking for.Like Shiftid correct In time, Out time.Forget about the query,just realize on paper, how you do it and what is the rule ?

Comment: Moreover this question should be shifted to Stackoverflow

Comment: Shift 1 refers to (Morning shift) ---shift 8 refers to night shift (11 to )... info provided is correct and these are irregular entries(not proper swipes) of employees (0 refrers to 'out' & 1 refers to 'IN')